# change main image by click left or right arrow or selecting actual image from thumbnail gallery in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

i'm developing a pdf book page viewer, i have many books that has more than 100 pages in my mysql database. so i fetch the book pages into my thumbnail gallery and if i select that image it will add img src to main image and display it on main image div, that works perfectly, here i have right and left arrow buttons next to main image, if i click these buttons the image should select next image or previous image. i was trying to get the idea and trying different source i could not get the output, please help me with this, i have added my codes bellow,

**PHP**

```
<button class="left-arrow" id="left-arrow">Left</buttom>
<img src="" alt="book" class="main-img" id="main-img">
<button class="right-arrow" id="right-arrow">Right</buttom>

<ul class="book-list id="book-list">
   <?php if ($total_page > 0) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($results as $row) : ?>
     <li class="book p-2">
     <span class="page-number"><?php echo $page_num++ ?></span>
     <img src="<?php echo PAGE_URL . "/" . $b_id . "/" . $row->page_name ?>" alt="Book Image">
     </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
   <?php endif ?>
 </ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bookPageList = $('#book-list');
    $(bookPageList).click(displayImage);

    function displayImage(e) {
        if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
            var target = e.target;
            var src = target.src;
            // console.log(src);
            $('#main-img').attr('src', src);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There's no database code here.

Comment: its just common data retrieve code thats why i did not add, do you want my query code?

Comment: If it's tagged MySQL then presumably the database code is relevant to the problem. If it isn't then snip that tag off to keep focused on the actual problem at hand, whatever that is.

Comment: noted. thank you for the tip

Comment: Are you sure `target.src` is returning the correct value? You may need to do `$(e.target).attr('src')` or, if `this` is set correctly as "the thing that was clicked" then `$(this).attr('src')` without having to dig through the event object.

Comment: yes it is returning the correct src

Comment: Ah, so that part of the code works. The "previous" and "next" stuff involves using `bookPageList` as an array and navigating through it. You'll need to figure out which element you're on, first.

Comment: yes, i'm thinking about add class 'active' on selected li but i dont know how to implement, i have tried that

Comment: With [`addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) when you select it, and if you keep that scope of `bookPageList` around you can easily `removeClass` on all of them before shifting that over one index, wrapping around at the end if necessary.

Comment: i dont get what you said, i have tried that addClass but it is adding active to every single list, if it is possible can you make as code what you said

Comment: Focus on only the active thing: `bookPageList.removeClass('active')` and then `$(this).addClass('active')`.

Comment: i have got, selected element active, and now for the buttons, what should i do, can you please explain me in the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue in this link, hope this help to other newbies

[Change image by selecting from thumbnail or next prev buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47902977/change-image-by-selecting-from-thumbnail-or-next-prev-buttons/47903211#47903211)