# Change image by selecting from thumbnail or next prev buttons

Tags: javascript, php

i'm developing a book page preview website which fetches book all page images (thumbnail) from file server through mysql database, clicking on a thumbnail will display that image on main div, also by clicking next or prev button it has to change the image from thumbnail and display it on main div.

i have done fetching images and click on thumbnail will display the image on main div and the buttons also working but when i change image by button it's not displaying on main div this my problem. i'm new to this php and javascript, i have followed the codes from this http://jsfiddle.net/Bgj4b/, i have put days on this still not figured out please help me.

This is my problem Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Looper/5r6qb5k3/

This is my actual codes

**PHP/HTML**

```html
<button class="left-arrow" id="left-arrow">Left</buttom>
   <img src="" alt="book" class="main-img" id="main-img">
<button class="right-arrow" id="right-arrow">Right</buttom>

<ul class="book-list id="book-list">
    <?php if ($total_page > 0) : ?>
        <?php foreach ($results as $row) : ?>
            <li class="book p-2">
                <span class="page-number"><?php echo $page_num++ ?></span>
                <img src="<?php echo PAGE_URL . "/" . $b_id . "/" . $row->page_name ?>" alt="Book Image">
            </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endif ?>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
$("#book-list li").click(function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    var src = target.src;

    $("#showcase-book-img").fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).on('load', function() { 
            $(this).fadeIn(); 
        });

        $(this).attr("src", src);
    });

    $("#book-list li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

$("#left-arrow").click(function(){
    if($("#book-list li.active").next("#book-list li").length>0){
        $("#book-list li.active").next().trigger("click");
    } else {
        $("#book-list li:first").trigger("click");//go to first
    }
    return false;
});

$("#right-arrow").click(function(){
    if($("#book-list li.active").prev("#book-list li").length>0){
        $("#book-list li.active").prev().trigger("click");
    } else {
        $("#book-list li:last").trigger("click");//go to end
    }
    return false;
});

$("#book-list li:first").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was wrong: You were firing event in `li` element. It has to be applied over its images.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/d2p0Ltmr/1/) the forking correction.

Comment: thank you very much mate, it's saved my time, i have to learn more javaScript